# A question related to Integral and supremum

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Let   $f\in L_{p}([0,1])$ and 1-periodic on $R^{1}.$ Suppose $[a,c]\subset [0,1].$ Are the   following quantities equal?
$$
\underset{|h|\leq \delta_{1}}{\sup}\int_{a}^{b}|f(x+h)-f(x)|^{p}dx+
\underset{|h|\leq \delta_{2}}{\sup}\int_{b}^{c}|f(x+h)-f(x)|^{p}dx 
$$
and
$$
\underset{|h|\leq \max\{\delta_{1}, \delta_{2}\}}{\sup}\int_{a}^{c}|f(x+h)-f(x)|^{p}dx
$$

Comment: Is $b$ arbitrary or fixed?

Comment: In general, no. Let $f$ oscillate with period $p_1 < \delta$ on $[a,b]$, and with period $p_2 < \delta$ on $[b,c]$.

Comment: @Simon. $b$ is fixed

Comment: @ Daniel. Is there any inequality between these quantities?

Comment: Sure, $\sup \int_a^c \leqslant \sup \int_a^b + \sup \int_b^c$.

Comment: @Daniel. Can we expect the opposite inequality if in the first integral $\delta=\delta_{1}$ in the second $\delta=\delta_{2}$ and in the third $\delta=\max\{\delta_{1}, \delta_{2}\}$

Comment: No, we can't expect that. If the periods are small enough and different in the right way, the inequality is strict (for suitable $f$) even with the different $\delta$s.

Comment: @ Daniel. I am doing a small research. My  function $f$ is 1-periodic function a.e. on $R^{1}$ with different $\delta$'s.  Sorry I have not mentioned it in question.  How about the opposite inequality now? I really appreciate your comments.